# Reflective properties of multifocal ellipses

Tags: geometry

As it is known, an ellipse has the following reflective property: when a ray of light originating from one focus reflects off the inner surface of an ellipse, it always passes through the other focus.

Do [multifocal ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse) (also known as $k$-ellipses) have also similar reflective properties?